# What is wrong with the program I have written in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

The question description is Write a program to get the input of key and value of the element in dictionary.

Display the key-value pair in the python dictionary format and find the length of the dictionary.

Test Case 1:

INPUT

```
3

23

33

43

32

33

34
```

OUTPUT

```
The dictionary is

{23: 32, 33: 33, 43: 34}

Length of dictionary is

3
```

**My code is:**

```
n = int(input())
di = dict()
for i in range(0, n):
  a = int(input())
  b = int(input())
  di[a] = b

print("The dictionary is")
print(di)
print("Length of dictionary is")
print(len(di))
```

The output I am getting for the same input given above is:

```
The dictionary is

{23: 33, 43: 32, 33: 34}

Length of dictionary is

3
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: looks like the dictionary is created key as a number reverse a number as a value. may be you have to store all the values in a list and then create dictionary

Comment: If you find an answer that responds to your question, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the input provided is in the following order:
i) size of the dictionary
ii) the keys
iii) the values

You seem to read it as key, value, key value ...

Answer (score 0):

The input provided is in the following order:

1. size of the dictionary
2. the keys
3. the values

So your code should look more like this :

```
# collecting length
n=int(input())

# creating lists for keys and values
keys_list = []
values_list = []

# collecting keys
for i in range(0,n):
  a=int(input())
  keys_list.append(a)

# collecting values
for i in range(0,n):
  a=int(input())
  values_list.append(a)

# creating dictionnary
di = dict(zip(keys_list, values_list)) 

# printing result
print("The dictionary is")
print(di)
print("Length of dictionary is")
print(len(di))
```

Like this, you're first collecting all the keys and putting them in a list, then you're collecting all the values and putting them in a list.
Finally, you're creating your dictionnary from these two lists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply this:

```
n = int(input('Input len of dict: '))

j = 0
l = []
while j != n * 2:
    l.append(input('input num: '))
    j += 1


di = {int(x): int(x[::-1]) for x in l[:3] if x[::-1] in l}
print(f"The dictionary is {di}\nLength of dictionary is {len(di)}")
```